# Can't parse json with node.js

Tags: html, json, parsing, web

I am a node.js beginner and I am trying to read a json file, but when I'm running 'npm start' in the terminal I get this error:

```
undefined:3462

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /Users/alonbond/node_apps/analoc_2/analoc/routes/index.js:15:20
    at fs.js:334:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

this is index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Welcome to Express.js');
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET json */
app.get('/analoc/', function(req, res) {

    fs.readFile('./sample_data.json', function(error, data){
        jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
        res.send('THE DATA: ', jsonObj);
    });

});

module.exports = app;
```

Any help?
thanks!

Comment: You're sure the file exists at that path and that there's content in the file?

Comment: yes. I have checked the file

Comment: BTW you can simple `require` json file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't parse a JSON in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767221/cant-parse-a-json-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

readFile is the asynchronous version. You should either just use readFileSync, or rewrite it to be properly asynchronous.

```
console.log('analoc request');

var fs = require('fs');

 fs.readFile('./files/sample_data.json', function(err,config){
console.log('Config: ' + JSON.parse(config));
});
```

Or:

```
var config = fs.readFileSync('./files/sample_data.json');
console.log('Config: ' + JSON.parse(config));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`readFile` doesn't have a return value](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback). You are trying to parse `"undefined"` as if it were JSON. The file is passed to the callback function after it has been read.

```
fs.readFile('./files/sample_data.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var config = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('Config: ', config);
});
```