# Can't parse a JSON in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

I am a Node.js beginner and I am trying to read a json file, but when I'm running 'npm start' in the terminal I get this error:

```
undefined:3462

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /Users/alonbond/node_apps/analoc_2/analoc/routes/index.js:15:20
    at fs.js:334:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

this is index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Welcome to Express.js');
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET json */
app.get('/analoc/', function(req, res) {

    fs.readFile('./sample_data.json', function(error, data){
        jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
        res.send('THE DATA: ', jsonObj);
    });

});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: maybe you can try/test if you have a valid json first here http://jsonlint.com/ it gives better error message if you have invalid json

Comment: You should also declare your variables (jsonObj), and put a console.log() on data to check.

Comment: Check if `error` is set...

Comment: What are the contents of sample_data.json?  As @Hokutosei says, try checking it using an online tool to ensure it's valid (if it's too complex to inspect by eye).

Comment: BTW, you could simply require() your JSON file.

Comment: @enguerranws: True, but I'm guessing the file(s) to read will vary based on the request, once he proceeds beyond prototyping.

Comment: how can I require a json file from a url though? for exmaple: http://files.analoc.com/test/sample_data.json

Comment: @AleksandrM not possible, exact duplicate, he has even copied the user name that posted the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. Your JSON file must be erroneous in some way.

Here this an example using your code:

invalid JSON:

```
{
    "test_data": 2
    bla
}
```

gives the error

```
Example app listening at http://:::3000
undefined:3
        bla
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token b 
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /tmp/node_help/index.js:15:32
    at fs.js:334:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

The error you get `Unexpected end of input` is normal when missing curly braces or parentheses in your JSON file.

Here is an invalid `sample_data.json` (missing a curly brace at the end):

```
{
    "test_data": 2
```

which gives the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /tmp/node_help/index.js:15:32
    at fs.js:334:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

Comment: Thanks! apparently my end of the json files was missing some parenthesis.